# Prove the following statement under open set

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose f is a continuous function on an open set Ω which has an anti-derivative on
Ω. 
if γ, γ' are two paths in Ω with the same beginning point and the same end point, are below statement true?
$$\int_{\gamma} f(z) \, dz =\int_{\gamma'} f(z) \, dz   $$

My approach: I think it should be the same, since it has two path in the same direction, but I am not sure how to approach this. Am I supposed to use Cauchy Integration theorem here?

Answer (score 0):

Since $f$ has an antiderivative on $\Omega$, Stokes theorem says that
$$
\int_\gamma f(z) \  \text{d} z = F(\gamma(1)) - F(\gamma(0))
$$
where $F$ is the antiderivative of $f$, for any path $\gamma : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}^n$ at all. Hence the two integrals are equal, because $\gamma$ and $\gamma'$ have the same endpoints ($\gamma(0) = \gamma'(0)$ and $\gamma(1) = \gamma'(1)$).

(With respect to a comment from the asker:) To be clear $\gamma(0)$ is to be interpreted as the start of the path $\gamma$, by definition, and similarly $\gamma(1)$ is the end of the path. After all, $\gamma$ is a function $[0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: That the integral of a derivative over a closed path is zero is definitely not true by the definition of the integral. This fact exactly follows from some version of the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: (The comment that was a response to got deleted.)

Comment: Beginners is Calculus know about Fundamental Theorem of Calculs but not Stoke's Theorem. I think Stoke's Throem is deep  (for many, may not be for me and you) and quoting it in this proof doesn't seem apporpriate to me.

Comment: @KeeleyHoek, is there some proof that having the same endpoints implies (γ(0)=γ′(0) and γ(1)=γ′(1))?

Comment: @mathrock1453 This is exactly the definition of having the same endpoints. because $\gamma(0)$ is the start of the path, by definition, and similarly $\gamma(1)$ is the end of the path. After all, $\gamma$ is a function $[0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}^n$.